# How to find out mySQL server ip address from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have access to my server's phpmyadmin. But how can I find that mysql's Ip address from phpmyadmin. My webserver and mysql is using different IPs.

Is there any way to find this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330898/find-server-ip-by-sql

Comment: @FrankerZ This question was asked 8 years ago around 7 years ago when you wrote you reply... he was seen for last time in 2012 you didnt really expect him to come back and accept an anwser?

Answer (score 49):

The SQL query **SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'** will show you the hostname of the MySQL server which you can easily resolve to its IP address.

**SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'** Will give you the port number.

You can find details about this in MySQL's manual: 12.4.5.41. SHOW VARIABLES Syntax and 5.1.4. Server System Variables

Answer (score 11):

MySQL doesn't care what IP its on. Closest you could get would be hostname:

```
select * from GLOBAL_variables where variable_name like 'hostname';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
```

Comment: If someone is trying to run this in phpMyAdmin, remove the 'select * from'. It should simply be: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'`

Answer (score 3):

The server's address is stored in [config.php](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#config)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, since you know the hostname, resolve the database server IP via  hostname from the web server.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

Answer (score -2):

You can ssh to your server and run this command

```
 ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

It worked for me..