# find server ip by sql

Tags: mysql

How can I get server ip (`host`) by a MySQL query?
an sql like this:

```
SELECT @@SERVERIP
```

I want to connect to my db by netbeans, and I can't use 'localhost' for `host`.

thanks

Comment: Can you use `127.0.0.1` for host?

Comment: `show variables like '%hostname%'`

Comment: Why? If you can connect to the server to execute such a query, you must already know either its hostname or its IP address, and once you have one of those, DNS will give you the other.

Comment: @EJP: because my shared hosting service do not allow direct connect to database server, and it hides its ip

Comment: So you can't connect to it, so you want to connect to it to ask it how to connect to it? This isn't making any sense..

Comment: @EJP: I can connect from my apps which hosted on that server, with using "localhost" as server. But I want remote connection to db server. (at least it's ip address)

Comment: @kikio If you're using localhost, MySQL is hosted on the same server. If you're unable to connect to it, it's because they don't permit external connections to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple try this.

You can get the[hostname][instancename] by:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

To get only the hostname when you have hostname\instance name format:

```
SELECT LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(@@ServerName)), Charindex('\', ltrim(rtrim(@@ServerName))) -1)
```

Alternatively as @GilM pointed out:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

Answer (score -1):

no you cannot here you can read from this thread :

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/224556