# Why am I getting "network request failed" error?

Tags: php, sql, react-native, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to insert data into my MySQL database but I'm getting an error that says "Network request failed" on my simulator.  I'm guessing `fetch()`'s it has something to do with my systems IP address (even though I entered the right one).

The `App.js` file is my React Native code. The `DBConfig.php` file identifies my database info. The `submit_user_info.php` file is responsible for populating the database and the `config.inc.php` (not included in this post because it's too long) file has my database configurations.

Note: `config.inc.php` is found in MAMP > bin > phpMyAdmin > config.inc.php

Note: In `DBConfig.php` I left `$HostUser` and `$HostPass` blank (`='')` because inside `config.inc.php`, on lines 568-569, both `$cfg['SQLValidator']['username']` and `$cfg['SQLValidator']['password']` are left blank.

[Error inside iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed6YJ.png)

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button } 
from 'react-native';

class ThisApp extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      TextInputName: '',
      TextInputEmail: '',
      TextInputPhoneNumber: ''

    }

  }

  InsertDataToServer = () =>{


 const { TextInputName }  = this.state ;
 const { TextInputEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { TextInputPhoneNumber }  = this.state ;


fetch('https://MySystemsIPAddress/submit_user_info.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    name: TextInputName,

    email: TextInputEmail,

    phone_number: TextInputPhoneNumber

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

// Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        Alert.alert(responseJson);

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


  }

  render() {
    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter Name"

          onChangeText={TextInputName => this.setState({TextInputName})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter Email"

          onChangeText={TextInputEmail => this.setState({TextInputEmail})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter Phone Number"

          onChangeText={TextInputPhoneNumber => this.setState({TextInputPhoneNumber})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <Button title="Insert Text Input Data to Server" onPress={this.InsertDataToServer} color="#2196F3" />



</View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10
},

TextInputStyleClass: {

textAlign: 'center',
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
// Set border Hex Color Code Here.
 borderColor: '#FF5722',

// Set border Radius.
 //borderRadius: 10 ,
}

});

export default ThisApp;
```

Here's `DBConfig.php`

```
<?php

//Define your host here.
$HostName = "localhost";

//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "UserInfo";

//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "";

//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "";

?>
```

Here's `submit_user_info.php`:

```
<?php

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

 // Populate name from JSON $obj array and store into $name.
$name = $obj['name'];

// Populate email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$email = $obj['email'];

// Populate phone number from JSON $obj array and store into $phone_number.
$phone_number = $obj['phone_number'];

 // Creating SQL query and insert the record into MySQL database table.
$Sql_Query = "insert into UserInfoTable (name,email,phone_number) values ('$name','$email','$phone_number')";


 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){

 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$MSG = 'Data Inserted Successfully into MySQL Database' ;

// Converting the message into JSON format.
$json = json_encode($MSG);

// Echo the message.
 echo $json ;

 }
 else{

 echo 'Try Again';

 }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct hostname/port? Is your server able to access the remote host?

Comment: @FrankerZ Yeah my hostname is localhost.  Where do I find port and where do I place that information?  When you say is my server able to access the remote host, do you mean if the URL `http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/` works?  If so, then yes.

Comment: Where are you seeing `Network request failed`?

Comment: @FrankerZ Inside the simulator.  I put DBConfig.php and submit_user_info.php inside the htdocs folder, forgot to mention that in my original post.

Comment: idk what that is. Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @FrankerZ ok, I did.  It's in my post.

Comment: Any chance you can run this in chrome/somewhere where you can see the actual request? My guess is your PHP has an error somewhere (Can't connect to your database, syntax error, or something else.) Seeing the output of the PHP script would go a long way to debug the issue.

Comment: @FrankerZ How would I run this on chrome to see the output of the PHP script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Comment: You can also try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128594/4875631

Comment: @FrankerZ Ok I'll try those in a bit but before I do.  Do you know exactly where I can find `$HostName`, `$HostUser` and `$HostPass` in myphpadmin?

Comment: Google my friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483268/how-to-find-out-mysql-server-ip-address-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @FrankerZ Nope :(

Comment: Edit your question, or add what you've tried/the steps you've taken so far.